# Overlaying of elements when selecting text

Tags: html, css

In This Code When I Select the output text I see this:

[image]

How can I fix it?

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo" rel="stylesheet">
<p>
  Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla
</p>
```

Comment: Line-height : 30px; ?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your **line-height** is smaller than your **font size**. So in order to fix it, keep your line-height equal to or greater than the font-size.

**Edit:** Setting a **display: inline;** fixes the issue.

Check it out here.

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo">
<p>
  Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla
</p>
```

Comment: That's weird. It's working on both Firefox and Chrome on my laptop. Which browser are you using ? Also, try increasing your line-height. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm ussing Chrome & Firefox

Comment: Adding display: inline; to your css will solve your problem. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem , try giving line height more than the font-size , In your case font-size is by default 16 px which is more than line-height .That is why it is overlapping.

check this out:

```css
p {
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo" rel="stylesheet">
<p>
  Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla Pla
</p>
```